# How to find the machine from which a user logged into current machine using ssh?

Tags: ssh, users, solaris, session

In a multi server architecture, is it possible to find out from which machine a user logged into current machine using `ssh`?

For example, `user1` logged into `host1`. From there, the user logged into `host2` as `sruser` using `ssh`.

In above example, would it be possible to trace the `sruser` session of `host2` back to `user1` session in `host1`?

Would it be possible to get the hostname or terminal of `user1` session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are an ordinary user on `host2`, you can see who is currently logged in from where with the `who` command, and who logged in from where in the past with the `last` command. Both show the remote host name or IP address for ssh logins; this is usually `host1`, but can be a gateway that relayed the ssh connection.

It is in principle impossible to know who `user1` is. After all, `host1` might not even be running a multiuser system, or might be an anonymous relay. This doesn't mean `user2` has absolute privacy amongst the known users of `host1`; for example, if you're the administrator on `host2`, and the user uses public key authentication, and you've configured the ssh server to dump information about the public key used, then you can find out the user's public key, and perhaps correlate it from information obtained elsewhere.

Some past questions on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) may interest you:

- https://superuser.com/questions/202123/if-someone-is-signed-into-ssh-on-my-computer-can-i-access-their-computer
- https://superuser.com/questions/174494/get-ssh-session-information

Answer (score 3):

The `who` and `last` commands might be useful for displaying the host from which users are connected.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Solaris but on Linux `lsof -u user | grep \:ssh` should work fine